# JSONP injected script did not invoke callback

Tags: angular, jsonp

I'm trying to get data from a Rest Api:

I tried following:

```
var headers: Headers= new Headers({  'dataType': 'jsonp'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.get('http://aaaddds.de/redmine/issues.json?limit=1200&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK', options)
      .map(this.extractData);
```

it doesn't work because of:

> ```
>  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header
> ```

So when I try JSONP

```
let params = new URLSearchParams();
params.set('callback', 'JSONP_CALLBACK');
params.set('project_id', '7');
params.set('key', '42d3db30ab061a9f630df1f476c4d127f98d5ad2');
params.set('limit', '1200');


return this.jsonp.get('http://aaaddds.de/redmine/issues.json', { search: params })
  .map(this.extractData);
```

it says :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: __ng_jsonp____req0finished is not defined
>   JSONP injected script did not invoke callback

When I do a Jquery ajax get it works:

```
   $.ajax({

      url: url,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function (datsa: any) {
        console.log(datsa);
      },
      error: function (e : any) { alert(e.toString) },
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that the parameter you provided for your callback isn't `callback`. In fact, this name depends on the target service and can be `callback`, `c` or something else...

To diagnose your problem, you should have a look at the Network tab of devtools in your browser to see the content of the response. It should be something like that:

```
__ng_jsonp__.__req0.finished({ ... })
```

`__ng_jsonp__.__req0` is the name of the callback internally handled by Angular2.

Comment: ok great the c worked, but is there a solution without the callback /c paramenter because my redmine Rest api wont allow me a callback /c parameter and returns null in the body

Comment: Great! I don't think that it's possible since Angular2 generates a callback name under the hood so it needs to be provided to the service so the latter can use this name in the response payload... How do your redmine Rest api get the callback name?

Comment: from redmine doc, it seems that `callback` or `jsonp` parameters can be used. See http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api

Answer (score 2):

I  solved this problem: set a variable:times

```
export class WikipediaService {
    constructor(private jsonp: Jsonp) {
        this.times=0;}
        search (term: string) {
        let wikiUrl = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php';
        let params = new URLSearchParams();
        params.set('search', term); // the user's search value
        params.set('action', 'opensearch');
        params.set('format', 'json');
        params.set('callback', `__ng_jsonp__.__req${this.times}.finished`);
        this.times=this.times+1;
        // TODO: Add error handling
        return this.jsonp
        .get(wikiUrl, { search: params })
        .map(response => <string[]> response.json()[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me! I added the counter as a private variable in the service.

Comment: `.set('callback', ng_jsonp_callback_${this.times}.finished);` for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
this._InstUrl = "your url";

let params1 = new URLSearchParams();
//params.set('search', term); // the user's search value
//params.set('action', 'opensearch');
params1.set('format', 'json');
//params1.set('callback', "ng_jsonp.__req0.finished");
params1.set('callback', "JSONP_CALLBACK");

    return this._jsonp
        .get(this._InstUrl, { search: params1 })
        .map(response => { debugger; this.Result = response.json().data })
        .subscribe(
        (data) => {
            debugger
            console.log(this.Result);
        },
        (error) => {
            debugger
            console.log(error);
        });
```

This one 100% working plz check

Comment: I am still having error  "JSONP injected script did not invoke callback."